# Bots still in signup database

Tags: function, recaptcha-enterprise

I have put enterprise on my website and still have bots in my database.  I have done the integrate client side, however I don't know how to send an HTTP POST with the info from request.json for the server side.  When do I use my secret code?  Please help.

I have tried to figure out how to send URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify METHOD: POST with the request.json information. I have put the information in the action php and that didn't work.  I have put the url in my browser and that didn't work either.  I have no idea how to do it.